# How to merge "list.txt" into cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here I have "list.txt" whose contents are as follows: (This list is the name of the folder)

```
2018-08-06
2018-08-07
2018-08-08
2018-08-09
2018-08-10
```

I want to combine it into a path. I tried the following script:

```
set drive_path=Z:\myfolder\2018\
set /p Build=<"list.txt"
echo %Build%%source%
```

**But only the first row is displayed.**

Then I tried to change the file "list.txt" whose contents are as follows:

```
"%drive_path%\2018-08-06"
"%drive_path%\2018-08-07"
"%drive_path%\2018-08-08"
"%drive_path%\2018-08-09"
"%drive_path%\2018-08-10"
```

But I still cannot solve this problem.

Please help me to make the final result as below and I hope there is no need to change "list.txt":

```
Z:\myfolder\2018\2018-08-06
Z:\myfolder\2018\2018-08-07
Z:\myfolder\2018\2018-08-08
Z:\myfolder\2018\2018-08-09
Z:\myfolder\2018\2018-08-10
```

Thankyou..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for /f` loop to iterate over the text file.

```
set "drive_path=Z:\myfolder\2018\"
for /f %%A in (list.txt) do (
    echo %drive_path%%%A
)
```

Comment: This really works, friend. but how do I write directly to the txt file?
if I try this script:
`> "list_fixed.txt"`
where do i put it?

Comment: @bede - after the last `)`

Comment: i try this: `set "drive_path=Z:\myfolder\2018\"
for /f %%A in (list.txt) do (
    echo %drive_path%%%A
)>list_fixed.txt`
but only first line displayed

Comment: i try this again: `set "drive_path=Z:\myfolder\2018\"
for /f %%A in (list.txt) do (
    echo %drive_path%%%A >"list_fixed.txt"
)
` same friend, only first line write to list_fixed.txt. How to fix friend?

Comment: Use the first one you tried, but use `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: thank you very much my friend, i can finish my script perfectly. God bless you..

Answer (score 1):

Doing `set /p Build=<"list.txt"` will only read the first line into a variable.

You need to use a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop.

```
rem notice there is no slash at the end of the path
set "drive_path=Z:\myfolder\2018"

for /f %%A in (list.txt) do (
    echo %drive_path%\%%A
)
```

**Explanation**:

`/f` - Allows us to loop through a command or a text file.

`%%A` - The variable that will hold the line, allowing us to work with it.

Comment: This is the same as my answer, except you're wrong about what `/f` is.

Comment: @SomethingDark - How about now?

Comment: Much better. Good job!

Comment: This really works, awesome friend. but how do I write directly to the txt file?
if I try this script:
`> "list_fixed.txt"`
where do i put it?

Comment: @bede - place that line inside the `for` loop. `>> list_fixed.txt`. If this is still causing you trouble, post another question, but don't forget to check mark an answer here.

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova - thank you very much my friend, i can finish my script perfectly. God bless you..

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova - √

Answer (score 1):

With the first version of your `list.txt`, the already existing answers work fine.

If you want to work with your second version (consisting of `"%drive_path%\2018-08-06"`-line entries), you have to evaluate the "variable" in your textfile. To do that, you need another layer of parsing. A simple `call` can deliver that:

```
set "drive_path=Z:\myfolder\2018"
for /f %%A in (list.txt) do call echo %%A
```